# Lucene.Net 3.0.5 - Near Real Time Search, reopening reader performance

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm indexing a sequence of documents with the IndexWriter and commiting the changes at the end of the iteration.

In order to access the uncommitted changes I'me using NRTS as described [here](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/06/lucenes-near-real-time-search-is-fast.html)

Imagine that I'm indexing 1000 documents and iterating through them to check if there's any I can reuse/update. (some specific requirements I have)

I'm reopening the reader at each iteration:

```
    using (var indexReader = writer.GetReader())
    using (var searcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader))
```

How slow should it be to reopen the reader? Once the index gets to around 300K documents, Occasionally, indexing 1000 documents can take around 60 seconds (not much text)

Am I taking the wrong approach? Please advise.

Comment: How often are you optimizing, and to how many segments?  Also, how many 'searching' users are you usually servicing?   I know what's working great for my app, but I also built in a settings file to tweak documents/commit and pause time between index loops.  Lucene itself indexes much faster than what you are seeing, my indexer spends ~90% of its time retrieving docs and extracting text (mine are PDFs).

Comment: @MichaelGorsich I'm optimizing at the end of each iteration. So, for an incoming 500 documents (each document is usually 2 paragraphs of text, plus metadata), I optimize at the end of their insertion. For the time being the service is serialized, meaning that only one thread is searching. I'm using the default settings for v3.0.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To increase your performance, you need to not optimize so often.

I use a separate timer for optimization.  Every 40 minutes it enables optimization to five segments (a good value according to "Lucene In Action"), which then occurs if the indexer is running (there being no need to optimize if the indexer is shut down).  Then, once a day, it enables optimization to one segment at a very low usage time of day.  I usually see about 5 minutes for the one-segment optimization.  Feel free to borrow my strategy, but in any case, don't optimize so often - your optimization is hurting your overall index rate, especially given that your document size is small, and so the 500 doc iteration loop must be happening frequently.

You could also put in some temporary logging code at the various stages to see where your indexer is spending its time so you can tweak iteration size, settling time between loops (if you're paranoid like me), optimization frequency, etc.

Comment: I agree with Michael, you're optimizing too much. I will, however, argue the point of never optimizing. Optimizing is nothing else than merging av segments (and in the process removing entries marked as deleted), something that Lucene already does automatically. You can change how this works by using different merge-policies (which decides which segments should be merged) if the default doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hi, Simon.  Could you clarify what you are saying?  I can't tell if you are suggesting never optimizing in certain conditions or if you misundesrstood my answer.  I was trying to say that my app optimizes every 40 minutes, but only if the indexer indexed something, and once a day, again if the indexer indexed something.   I tend to see clumps of new documents, then nothing for a couple days, etc  We all need to analyze our optimization strategy for our own apps, I was just giving an example. : )

Comment: I'm agreeing with your answer and that the need for optimization is situational. I'm just added a comment to argue that optimization may not be needed at all; Lucene's normal merging of segments may be enough.

Comment: For the most part, I agree.  I can't tell the difference in search speed between 5 segments and 1 segment, but there was a measureable difference between none and 5 over 1.6 million medium sized docs.  Measureable...but not really significant from a user perspective.  Nobody's going to put in a help desk ticket because it took 3 seconds rather than 2.5 seconds to find their doc.  ;^}

Comment: Somewhat after the fact, but... I would go further than Simon and say "never optimize". Don't Flush either (except in very special circumstances). The only possible exception for Optimize is if you are bulk inserting into an index that will then be read-only. For an index that is taking updates Lucene is _designed_ to expect many segments. It has built in heuristics to merge segments together when there are too many or they become too sparse (deletes). See LogMergePolicy for tuning parameters.

Comment: @AndyPook When you mention not to flush either, except in very special circumstances, could you expand on that?

Comment: Flush will force all buffered docs to be sent to disk as a new segment. Causing extra IO will hurt performance. It is usually a _much_ better idea to just let L's heuristics figure out when to flush and merge. You can fiddle with the properties of the MergePolicy to tell L to flush/merge earlier or later (use the memory options not the # of doc versions).     Now, depending on your usage patterns (infrequent updates) you may want to have a timer that flushes after a period of time. However, you can end up triggering a flush moments after L has just done on itself (these are tricky to track)

Comment: There are a few scenarios where this might be acceptable (you need 100% of updates to be persisted) but this is not good for perf. You end up with lot's of tiny segments forcing L to merge more frequently. Similarly, optimizing is only a good idea if your index is read-only. Optimizing causes _a lot_ of IO and may stall your searches. Again there are MergePolicy properties for defining when and how big segments can get. OS's are good at handling file descriptors. Just let L deal with it.